# Qualify Lead in MS CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

I'm newbie to CRM. I want to qualify a lead to create opportunity. I'm passing following parameters as request

*CreateOpportunity*
*CreateAccount*
*CreateContact*
*customerid*
*targetentityname*
*targetentityid*
*requestname*
*transactioncurrencyid*
*statuscode*
*subject*
*fullname*
*lastname*
*companyname*
*createdby*
*campaignid*

But am getting **Insufficient parameter** error as response.

Can anybody help me out by providing the missing parameters?

Answer (score 0):

In case you need to create only opportunity from your lead it's completely enough to pass next parameters to **QualifyLeadRequest**:
1. CreateOpportunity
2. OpportunityCurrencyId
3. OpportunityCustomerId
4. Status
5. LeadId

Please take a look at sample code below
C#:

```c#
var rmc = new RetrieveMultipleRequest()
{
    Query = new QueryExpression("organization")
    {
        ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("basecurrencyid")
    }
};
var rmc_r = (RetrieveMultipleResponse)serviceProxy.Execute(rmc);
//Qualify lead
var qlr = new QualifyLeadRequest()
{
    CreateOpportunity = true,
    OpportunityCurrencyId = rmc_r.EntityCollection.Entities[0].GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("basecurrencyid"),
    OpportunityCustomerId = new EntityReference("account", new Guid(<your-existing-account-guid>)),
    //3 is statuscode value "Qualified" for lead entity 
    Status = new OptionSetValue(3),
    LeadId = new EntityReference("lead", new Guid(<your-existing-account-guid>))
};
```

Please take a look at **SOAPLogger** (SDK\SampleCode\CS\Client\SOAPLogger) tool distributed with Dynamics CRM SDK to get request XML string and send as request payload from your client extensions (JavaScript).

[via](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh547458.aspx)

Comment: I want to create opportunity,contact and account. Then what are all the parameters I have to pass? @mayCrip

Comment: You should set **CreateContact**, **CreateAccount** to true

Comment: after setting both as true. Is we need any additional parameters to be passed? @mayCrip

Comment: No. You don't need to set any additional parameters but I forgot about removing **OpportunityCustomerId** parameter which is redundant in case you would like to create Opportunity, Account, Contact from lead.